# Agregar un valor dependiendo del valor en la tabla del orm

Tags: python, serialización

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y tengo un problema en la siguiente parte.

Tengo un modelo de bd en la cual he declarado la placa, marca, etc. De igual forma tengo los serializer y mis views. Mi problema viene al momento de mostrar la data, ya que necesito que cuando la marca sea TOYOTA me de como resultado 1, cuando la marca sea HONDA me de 2 y asi sucesivamente con cada marca. Esto resultados solo se deberán ver en la vista, ya que en la bd seguira registrado como Toyota u Honda.

models.py

```
class auto(models.Model):

     placa = models.IntegerField()

     marca = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

serializer.py

```
class autoserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
          model = auto
          fields = ('placa', 'marca')
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])

def auto_api_view(request):

    autos = auto.objects.all()

    autos_serializer = autoserializer(autos,many=True)

    return Response(autos_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

RESULTADO OBTENIDO:

```
{

  'placa':'ABX-123',

  'marca':'toyota',

}
```

RESULTADO ESPERADO:

```
{

  'placa':'ABX-123',

  'marca':'1',

}
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Lo correcto sería tener una tabla de marcas donde almacenes el `id, nombre` (1, "TOYOTA") y en las otras tablas simplemente anotas el `id` de la marca.